# Creating a triangle centered below all but last list items

Tags: css, html-lists

I want to create a triangle below the center of each `li` element but not the last one.

html

```
<ul class="steps-ul">
  <li> Step 1: Hardware Mounting </li>
  <li> Step 2: Hardware Connection </li>
  <li> Step 3: Devices Connection </li>
  <li> Step 4: Initial Test </li>
</ul>
```

css

```
.steps-ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
}

.steps-ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color:#efefef;
}
.steps-ul li:nth-child(odd)::after {
  border-top: 20px solid #efefef;
}
.steps-ul li {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background-color:#d7d7d7;
}
.steps-ul li::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 270px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #d7d7d7;
}
```

[Heres a screenshot of what i would like to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0agG.png)

I attempted using the `::after` psuedo element within css but no results.

Comment: Your `::after` selector needs `content`, this can be a single space `" "`, in order to display it.

Comment: great! thank you so much. that and adding `position: absolute` got my little box showing. Im sure i can take it from here.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: This question did not require debugging.

Comment: You can edit your question and instead of codepen you can use code snippets in Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Rob fixed on april 10th just so you know. my apologies, seems like things have become a tad more strict around here since 2010 :)

Does this question still have to remain closed being that i updated the post?

Comment: @Rob The code i provided compared to the code provided in the answer i accepted is far from duplicated. I would appreciate a second moderators opinion here, and if more clarification on what your referring to when you say "the answer you accepted shows your question is a duplicate"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `::after` selector is missing a `content` property, which is required for pseudo elements to be displayed.

```css
.steps-ul li::after {
  content: " ";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
}
```

Copied the triangle code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-do-css-triangles-work).

As for not adding the triangle to the last element, you can use the `:not(:last-child)` selector.

Comment: Wait so i didn't need `position: absolute;`?

Comment: The question is off topic as it does not supply a [mcve] here, within the question. Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]